# Problems after porting Visual Studio Qt4 app to Qt5

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5

I have a Qt4-based C++ app utilizing the QWizard class. It's a very simple app and is essentially just a wizard. It doesn't use QtCreator, instead it's a Visual Studio Project (I don't know why, but I suppose it's because the project was initially rather small and all of our other projects use Visual Studio). As such, there is no .pro file and instead all commands like moc.exe are setup manually in the VS project.

I need to port the app over to Qt5 as it's having a lot of rendering problems when DPI settings are changed on Windows, and from what I've read Qt5 has better support for that (and eventually I'd want to migrate anyways).

I read the document from Qt regarding transitioning from Qt4 to Qt5 and downloaded the latest version of Qt (I did not build it myself, something I could try I suppose).

I adapted some of the API calls that changed and also adapted the headers (QtWidgets instead of QtGui etc.).

The problem I am running into is that I'm getting a ton of "cannot find file" errors from various header files. It starts with the global header file qglobal.h which has

```
#ifdef QT_BOOTSTRAPPED
#include <QtCore/qconfig-bootstrapped.h>
#else
#include <QtCore/qconfig.h>
#include <QtCore/qtcore-config.h>
#endif
```

I didn't have `QT_BOOTSTRAPPED` defined so got errors about neither one of the header files being found, so I defined `QT_BOOTSTRAPPED`. I am somewhat perplexed that I would get this error out of the box.

After making this change some of the files started compiling, but I get further errors from various *global.h files, including:

- qtguiglobal.h: Complains that **QtGui/qtgui-config.h** can't be found
- qtwidgetsglobal.h: Complains that **QtWidgets/qtwidgets-config.h** can't be found

Example:

```
qt5\src\qtbase\include\qtgui\../../src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal.h(44): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/qtgui-config.h': No such file or directory
```

I'm at a complete loss here. I have no idea what those "...-config.h" files are, what they are used for, and why they don't exist on my machine.

Other errors I get are:

```
error C2065: 'QT_VERSION_MAJOR': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'QT_VERSION_MINOR': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'QT_VERSION_PATCH': undeclared identifier
```

I could obviously define those, but that doesn't seem like the correct approach?

I did some due diligence but wasn't able to find anybody else having this problem, and was also not able to find any documentation on those files from Qt itself (which I find mildly frustrating).

I'm far from a Qt expert, this is one of three projects utilizing a Qt GUI that is fairly static and usually just gets minor tweaks, most of which aren't related to Qt all.

Comment: I was able to get by the "file not found" errors by creating those files from scratch, based on templates I found online. It looks like I'm missing some step after installing Qt, but I don't know what it is?

Comment: Which Qt version did you install? Did you install it from the online installer? Can you edit your question to include the first few errors you got originally? Missing `-config.h` files are usually a result of not rerunning configure when building a new module in an existing Qt build. Maybe include your .pro file as well. I suspect that `there is no .pro file and instead all commands like moc.exe are setup manually in the VS project` is the problem though. Are you using the Qt Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: I downloaded version 5.10, the (I believe) current version. I'm not sure what other errors you are referring to, all the errors I got are above. All I did was install Qt with the unified installer, thinking that it would be all I need. I will just try to build it from source like I have in the past, maybe it will work. Pretty disappointed, I remember struggling with Qt4 and their lack of documentation 5+ years ago, apparently it hasn't improved much.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not using the VS PlugIn.

Comment: Why don't you use the VS Plugin? The process when using Creator is smooth, but I wouldn't try to use VS without the plugin. I'm not sure what you mean about the documentation, but you should create bug reports if you have a suggestion for how it could be improved.

Comment: Are you sure *config.h files are indeed absent rather than they're not found by VS? It would mean that the Qt installer failed, reintallation is the first thing to try, but I doubt this is the case. Just rephrasing what Mitch has said: can you create a pro file (running [qmake -project](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html) may help to start) then import the created project into VS using the VS plugin? Don't use older VS projects for Qt4 apps unless you know how to fix them. Config files contain macro keys from Qt configuration script, they're internal and undocumented by design.

Comment: The error message you give looks very odd.  I wouldn't expect to see text such as `\src\qtbase\include` or `src/gui/kernel/` anywhere in such messages.  It almost looks as if you are compiling against files that are actually in the `Qt` source tree rather then under `/usr/include` (or wherever they are installed under Windows).  What are the various include paths being passed to the compiler?

Comment: @G.M. - I think you may be on to something. Apparently there are multiple folders inside the directory where I installed it - I'm checking this out now. Thanks!

Comment: @G.M. - Incredible - that was actually it! I can't believe that when I searched for that file, I never searched outside the "src" directory. Qt actually creates a msvc2015 (and an equivalent for 64 bit). I mistakenly thought that this directory would only have the binary files (.lib, .dll) and I had pointed the linker there, but I didn't realize that the include files were there as well. So now I just have to fix the compiler errors related to unicode/u_short/wchar_t etc. If you want to post your comment as the answer instead then I'll mark it accordingly.